# Vimeo - videos.getChannels

Tags: api, vimeo

How can I efficiently retrieve a list of channels that a Vimeo video is listed in from the [Advanced Vimeo API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods)?

The [Advanced Vimeo API](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods) provides the methods `channels.addVideo` and `channels.removeVideo` for managing the channels a video belongs to.  Also, the `channels.getVideos` method is provided for retrieving the list of videos belonging to a channel.

However, there is no `videos.getChannels` method.  This means that in order to find all the channels a video is included in one would need to call `channels.getVideos` (possibly more than once if the channel has more than 50 videos) for each channel of interest.  This seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: Hi, Did you find the answer for this? Now oauth 2.0 is introduced. Does it work fine now? Please give the solution if you have.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen so far it has not been implemented into v1, but will be added into v2. I am still looking to see if there is an alternative

edit*

take a look at this page because they have this method `vimeo.channels.getAll`

[VIMEO](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/methods/vimeo.channels.getAll)

I know this will get you a list of channels, from there I dont know if you can compare that to the video to make a list of channels that the video is in. I'm still looking.